# Why is Outlook removing filenames from embedded pictures

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook-web-access

This problem exists in multiple Exchange environments (confrimed on hosted Exchange 2013, Office 365) across mutiple versions of Outlook (confirmed on 2013, 2016)

I get an email with an embedded photo.

In Outlook client I can right-click the photo and "Save as Picture"
From here I get a save as dialogue box where I have to provide a file name. 
Using OWA however, I right click on the embedded picture and I can select "Save Image As" and my save as dialogue box pre-fills the file name with the original source filename.

I have attached screen captures of both examples.

It is clear from OWA that the meta-data in the embedded image includes the filename, however Outlook is not parsing that meta-data.

Outlook:
[image: Outlook Example]

OWA:
[image: OWA Example]

Does anybody know of a way to get Outlook to pre-fill the save-as dialogue with the embedded photo's original filename, similar to how OWA does?

2nd OWA example:
[[image: OWA Example 2[3]]

Answer (score 0):

OWA is not doing what you think it is...

When using Firefox (as you seem to be, judging by your screenshot), it always suggests "Image00X.jpg" as appears in your example image (X = a number, depending on how many images are embedded in the email, and which image of the set you pick).

Chrome behaves the same way.

In IE(11), right-clicking and saving an embedded picture always suggests "untitled.jpg" as the default file name.

Comment: Not true at all. OWA Is doing exactly what I say. I have another screen capture showing this behavior with a quite complex file name. One that obviously used to name the original embedded photo. Let me see how I can attach it here.  How can I attached another photo here?

Comment: I attached a 3rd screen capture to the main (original) post. You will see that I mean. Still seeking a solution. I do see what you mean with IE though. However, the fact that Firefox is pulling the original file name means it is still there somewhere and I need Outlook to do the same.